# OFSSET + transpose

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, offset, transpose

I'm trying to reduce the amount of documents e have and one of the tasks is to have all information fed by a form and then Google Sheets to sort it.

At the moment I have that all the responses are in one row for every product. However, I would like it to be duplicated 5 times, once for each possible food component wasted. Ive used these 2 formulas in A2 and K2 in the HOLDING V! tab:

```
=OFFSET(responses!$A$2,ceiling((row()-1)/5,1)-1,column()-1)

=OFFSET(responses!$A$2,ceiling((row()-1)/5,1)-1,mod(row()-2,5)*9+10,1,3)
```

Even tho it does use the 3 columns I want, it does not write the component 2, 3, 4 and 5 and its respective KG and Holding. I wonder if there is a way of doing that a I've tried different ways of formulating that.

The final table should look something like this:

From column K to M on the HOLDING tab:

```
stew base / 4 / Charity

frozen sweetcorn / 4 / Charity

frozen sweetcorn / 4 /Charity

""" / "" / ""

"" / "" / ""

test / 6 / Charity

testing5 / 4 / Charity

frozen sweetcorn / 4 / Charity

olives / 4 / Charity

basil / 4 / Charity
```

I hope this makes sense and I've added the file I'm currently using for this exercise.

I all honesty I would prefer to use a query so the data is pulled automatically but I'm unsure if this is possible at all.

Thank you in advance

[Google Sheets - Wastage reduction](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9CY8Uie2GZEqgZtqy5iU9UO-E1lU87e2V5BzWTj4XE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you allow access to the sheet plz?

Comment: Despite you shared the Spreadsheet it's unaccessible for us. It'd be helpful to have access as @TomSharpe mentioned.

Comment: @TomSharpe and Jose I've now updated the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well the short answer is just a couple of typos in the formula - it should always specify a height of 1 row and a width of 3 columns and offset an extra 3 columns for each row you go down:

```
=OFFSET(responses!$A$2,ceiling((row()-1)/5,1)-1,mod(row()-2,5)*3+10,1,3)
```

[image]

A single formula version would use almost the same calculation:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(ceiling((row(A2:A)-1)/5,1)+1,{row(A2:A),responses!A2:Z},
{mod(row(A2:A)-2,5)*3+12,mod(row(A2:A)-2,5)*3+13,mod(row(A2:A)-2,5)*3+14}))
```

Comment: This was great - thank you so much. I tried to use the array formula but gave me ref error but I'm happy with the current solution for now. Thank you again

Comment: Just a note to say that I've also tried the arrayformula but it doesn't seem to work and returns a #REF error. Unsure why this would be. Any advice?

Comment: It works for me with the original data which I copied from your sheet. Does the ref error give you any more information if you hover over it?

Comment: Hi Tom, yes it does work - the reference error was because the sheets had different number of total rows. Its been resolved now